# Origen de "bla" como onomatopeya en español

Tags: etimología, onomatopeyas

Me da hoy por buscar el origen de ***[bla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5e1JoZ5)*** como onomatopeya usada "repetida para imitar el ruido del habla ininterrumpida y previsible". Pensaba que sería una palabra con una larga trayectoria en el idioma, pero sorprendentemente (para mí) veo que es bastante reciente:

- En el NTLLE no aparece. En 2001 se incorporó al diccionario la expresión [*blablablá* o *bla-bla-blá*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/). Y no fue hasta 2014 que se incorporó *bla* a secas.
- En el CORDE veo algunos casos, siendo el más antiguo de 1970: *Susan la escuchaba de memoria y se iba soplando tanto bla-bla-blá con sus palabritas en francés intercaladas de vez en cuando*.
- En la hemeroteca de la BNE veo un posible caso en 1955, pero es de una obra de acceso restringido y no puedo asegurarlo. Veo también algún que otro caso suelto en la década de 1960.
- El *Diccionario de americanismos* define *[blablá](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=blabl%C3%A1)* como de uso en varios países hispanoamericanos, con significados similares. Pero ignoro desde cuándo se usa.
- La web de *Etimologías de Chile* solo [dice que](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?blablabla.-) los grupos *bl* y *br* se han empleado desde antiguo para designar un habla poco inteligible. Cita como ejemplos la palabra *bárbaro* para designar al que tiene un habla incomprensible, y *balbuceo* para aquel que dice cosas poco comprensibles.
- En el diccionario etimológico abreviado de Corominas no aparece.

La web de Etymonline cita el origen del inglés *[blah](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blah#etymonline_v_13565)* hacia 1918 con el sentido de "idle, meaningless talk" (similar pues al sentido español), lo que puede indicar que la palabra se importó desde el inglés. Por las fechas podría coincidir con la apertura de España a la cultura inglesa en la década de 1960 (coincidiendo con Los Beatles).

¿Fue así? ¿Es la onomatopeya *bla* un anglicismo? ¿O es en realidad más antigua solo que no se registró por escrito hasta en años recientes? ¿Cuándo y cómo se introdujo al español?

Comment: [*Las mujeres y el bla bla bla*](https://books.google.es/books?id=LQxYAAAAMAAJ&q="bla"&dq="bla"), Visión, vol.45, 1950 | "Qué series interminable de blablabla!" [*El Noticiero bibliográfico - Volumes 2-5 - Page 155*](https://books.google.es/books?id=vvUvAAAAYAAJ), 1940

Comment: @ukemi pues sí que se me habían escapado referencias anteriores...

Comment: En el [English language & usage, ver respuesta no aceptada](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316495/where-does-blah-meaning-idle-talk-come-from?answertab=votes#tab-top) mencionan a Oxford English dictionary "I certainly wouldn't be able to answer this question with any more authority than the OED, which attests "blah" in 1918, originally from the U.S. No me extrañaría que fuera un anglicismo. [Ngram google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blah&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblah%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Y abre el debate con su possible origen mejicano: "from 1848, suggesting that the term was first used by Spanish speakers in Mexico and the Southern United States, perhaps to catch on among other U.S. speakers in English."

Comment: Siempre he supuesto que la expresión "blah blah blah" en inglés se originó en "habla, habla, habla". La expresión era común en Texas hace muchos años.

Comment: Pues sí, hay que echar un ojo a la respuesta relacionada que encontró @AlexBcn.

Comment: Se usa también en francés desde los años 40 del siglo XX y, respecto a la [etimología](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bla-bla), se hipotiza que puede tener relación con el verbo francés "blaguer" (véase también [aquí](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/bla-bla)).

Answer (score 1):

Cabe la posibilidad de que proceda de "bar bar", de origen en la antigua grecia, y que es también el origen de la palabra bárbaro.
"Bar bar" sería la manera en que se referían a los sonidos de las lenguas extranjeras (no latín ni griego), porque les sonaban a balbuceos.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A1rbaro